# Symfony : Entity of type "App\Entity\Classement" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I have this form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Country::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                          ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
        ->add('season', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Season::class,
            'choice_label' => 'year',
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.year', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
        ->add('clubHistos', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ClubHistoType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false
            ],
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Classement::class,
    ]);
}
```

Here is my ClubHistoType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('position', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('matches', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('victories', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('draws', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('losses', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('goals', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('points', null, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('season', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Season::class,
            'choice_label' => 'year',
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.year', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
        ->add('club', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Club::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => '-',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            }
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ClubHisto::class,
    ]);
}
```

And my function to create a new country table in my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("back/table/new", name="new_table")
 */
public function createCountryTable(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager) {
    $countryTable = new Classement();

    $clubHistoriques = new ClubHisto();
    $countryTable->addClubHisto($clubHistoriques);
    
    $form = $this->createForm(ClassementType::class, $countryTable);
    dd($form);
    
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // foreach($clubHistoriques as $histo) {
        //     $histo->setSeason($countryTable->getSeason());
        // }
        $manager->persist($countryTable);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('edit_table', ['id' => $countryTable->getId()]);
    }


    return $this->render('back/createTables.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

}
```

But as soon as I call the form, it gives me this error :

Entity of type "App\Entity\Classement" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

I don't really understand because I have other forms that work exactly like this one and everything works fine...

I know this subject has been asked many times, but the solutions never worked that were given never really worked.

Your help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try just instantiate your form without `$countryTable`

```
$form = $this->createForm(ClassementType::class);
```

You already bind the form to the data so you shouldn't need to pre-instantiate it.

Then handle the data inside your `if (form->isSubmitted())` logic

```
/* @var $countryTable \App\Entity\Classement */
$countryTable = $form->getData();
$clubHistos = $countryTable->getClubHistos();
```